# DeployR using RBroker Java

Tags: java, r, deployr

I am new to using `DeployR` (started yesterday) and I would like to know what `URL` does the constructor of the `RBrokerConfig` class need.
Is it the `URL` for the landing page?
Or does it just need the basic `URL` (**http://localhost:8000**)?

Answer (score 1):

You require an endpoint URL. If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-rbroker-framework/blob/master/src/DeployRBroker/RBrokerConfig.cs) you can see that you would need something like

```
 /// <param name="deployrEndpoint">URL indicating the DeployR endpoint 
 ///  (i.e  http://localhost:7300/deployr )</param>
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall take a look at that